# Can't install Unity5 in Ubuntu20.04

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to install an older version of Unity. Unity5 in my Ubuntu20.04LTS system. But it doesn't work. Here is what I'm getting: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kH82L.jpg

Unity is just stuck after that. Nothing.

My try was:

```
./UnityHub.AppImage unityhub://5.6.0f3/497a0f351392
```

I need Unity 5 to run a really old project.

And hub does only enlist the newest releases:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to install it directly from/via the hub?

Comment: @derHugo yes, and they don't offer older versions

Comment: For old versions of Unity to work you may also need an old version of your operating system. I don't know about Ubuntu but it may be the same as on macOS: Unity 5.6 doesn't work on Big Sur anymore.